# solr search php html front-end

Tags: php, html, solr

I got my solr working with help of many of stackoverflow's questions and the solr has some mysql data (multiple tables). It returns the results perfectly to my browser (multiple facets).

Making selections via the url bar works aswell. Now i'm at the fase that I want the php code to generate the corresponding urls for the filter options. At a later stage i want to be able to select multiple option (eg red and blue) via checkboxes, this will requere some javascript i assume. But for now it just needs to append the selected "filter" to the url.

Preferably I will sent a GET request instead of some form / POST request for performance reasons and have something (link or button) to clear the selection. Is there a special frontend for this or is it done somewhere in the solr?

There is not a lot of information or examples on this, at least I could not get to it.

The setup is:
client > webserver > php > php pecl solr > solr > php > html > client

Any pointers?
Regards

Comment: Possibly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633479/looking-for-solr-frontend

Answer (score 0):

You should read Solr UserGuide if needed, then pecl install solr
Then you will have a your solr client,
use SolrClient, SolrQuery and other classes as needed

All of them are documented here:
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php